# Binary Search Tree - What is the difference between Value and Key?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm confused on what the difference is between a Key and a Value in a BinarySearchTree Node is. What is the point of a Key? Can't you base the BST off of a value alone? Here are two code samples that include Key and Value. They are two different pieces of code that I got from two different sources.

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
class Node
{
private:
public:
Node<Key, Value>(Key key, Value value)
{
this->key = key;
this->value = value;
N = 1;
left = NULL;
right = NULL;
};
Node* left; 
Node* right; 
Key key; 
Value value; 
int N; 
};
```

And the second piece of code is;

```
void insert(int value)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        root = new Node(value);
    else
        insertHelper(root, value);
}

void insertHelper(Node* node, int value)
{
    if(value < node->key)
    {
        if(node->leftChild == NULL)
            node->leftChild = new Node(value);
        else
            insertHelper(node->leftChild, value);
    }
    else
    {
        if(node->rightChild == NULL)
            node->rightChild = new Node(value);
        else
            insertHelper(node->rightChild, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Value is just something that is attached to the node.  It is the node's payload, if you like.

Comment: Also, there are more interface requirements from key types, while value types only need to be copy-able, usually.

Comment: So what is the Key if the Value is the Nodes Value? Let's say i'm making a list of numbers and I want the nodes Value to be 10, what would I make the Key and what would be the point of it?

Comment: Think of it in terms of boxes with stuff: the "value" is the stuff that's inside the box. The "key" is what is written on the box, to help you put the box in the right place and to, later, find it again.

Answer (score 3):

Value is just something that is attached to the node. It is the node's payload, if you like.  It is an arbitrary primitive type or object.

The Key is used to determine where to insert the node into the tree.  Note that Value doesn't participate at all in developing and maintaining the tree structure like Key does.

Nik provided a good analogy:  A node is a container.  The Value is what you put into that container, and the Key is how you mark the container so that you can retrieve it later.

Comment: So what would be an example of a key if I'm making a list of numbers?

Comment: @user2130537 The number itself. There's nothing wrong with making the value be the key, but it's not really a very useful thing most of the time.

Comment: The number is the Key.  The Value can also be a number (even the same number), but it could also be an image of the number, or something else entirely.  Do you see the difference?

Comment: Agreed. Which is why i'm confused on why a Key needs to be involved at all. Why not just form the tree off the value?

Comment: Because you may want to store something else in the Value besides just the numerical Key.  Maybe you want to store the string "Three" in node 3.  Or a [picture of Hugh (third of five)](http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120218232521/memoryalpha/en/images/4/40/Hugh-Drone.jpg).  The Value doesn't have to have any correspondence to the Key at all (although in practice it usually does).

Comment: @user2130537 What if you're storing the seven wonders of the world? How do you "form the tree" from the wonders themselves? In that case, it makes sense to just assign each wonder a number. The wonder is the value, its number is the key.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hugh? Really? A picture of [Seven of Nine](http://trekcore.com/gallery/albums/sevenofnine/7of9_s4a.jpg) is way easier on the eyes.